# How to rename a folder from DDMS in eclipse emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I want to rename the folder from DDMS. The DDMS only supports deletion of a file and an empty folder. I want to change the name of folder `/mnt/sdcard/NewFolder` to `/mnt/sdcard/NewFolder2`. Is there a way to rename the folder?

Comment: @ChiragRaval you're not right. According to SO rules it is possible to answer to own questions. If it is not allowed, you will not have a button to answer your own question.

Comment: It's possible, if you for instance have made a research before on this question and now just share you knowledge with the community. However, I'm a bid agree with you because the question does not seem to me difficult and, moreover, the answer is not correct with respect to question (there is a question how to do this in ddms and not in a shell).

Comment: @ChiragRaval I'm not doing this to earn reputation, I'm just sharing knowledge. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @ChiragRaval dont think other people cheap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command in cmd:

```
C:\> adb shell
$ cd /mnt/sdcard
$ mv NewFolder NewFolder2
```

Comment: what about for renaming from private files located in data?